# Printing Classification Report in FastText Text Classification output

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-classification, multilabel-classification, fasttext

I want to print classification report and F1 score by using sklearn.metrics library but it needs the predicted labels. Fasttext gives only the output in fig2, so I wonder is there any easy way to get these labels and print classification report?

```
def train():
    self.model = fasttext.train_supervised(input='train.txt', wordNgrams=2, lr=1.0, epoch=10,
                                           bucket=200000, dim=300, loss='hs', pretrainedVectors='../cc.tr.300.vec')
    predict = self.model.test('test.txt')

    print(predict)
```

[Fasttext Train and Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftMJC.png)

[Output Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvhc8.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving test.txt to the model.test, get all sentences one by one in a loop and predict each one and insert to the list.

```
self.pred = []
for sentence in self.sentences:
    self.pred.append(self.model.predict(sentence)[0][0].replace('__label__',''))

classification_report(y_true=self.real_tags, y_pred=self.pred, zero_division=0)
```